# A nonparametric residual bootstrap for random-effects models

Tags: mixed-model, nonparametric, bootstrap, multilevel-analysis

This question regards ideas from "A novel bootstrap procedure for assessing
the relationship between class size and achievement".

The authors first describe a parametric bootstrap for random-effects models (which I understand). This is briefly described below.

Consider data from a two-level hierarchy, which would represent pupils (level 1)
within classes (level 2). Let $j =1, \dots, J$ index the $J$ classes and $i=1, \dots , I_j$ index the $I_j$ pupils in the $j$th class, with data $Y_{ij}$ . Denote by $x_{ijk}$ and $z_{ijk}$ $(k = 0, \dots ,K)$ the $k$th element of the $K + 1$ covariates for the fixed and random part of the model for observation $Y_{ij}$ , where $x_{ij0} =z_{ij0} =1$. The dimension of the fixed and random parts of the model need not be equal but it is assumed for notational simplicity. The normal error model is

\begin{equation}
y_{ij} = \sum_{k=0}^K\beta_kx_{ijk} + \sum_{k=0}^Ku_{jk}z_{ijk} + e_{ij},
\label{Eq_random_effects}
\end{equation}

where the $\beta$s are fixed effects, the $u$s are random class effects from a $(K+1)$ - dimensional normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and $e_{ij}$ are independent identically distributed errors (at the pupil level) from an $N(0, \sigma^2_e)$ distribution and are independent of the $u$s.

We assume that the parameters $(\beta, \Sigma, \sigma^2_e)$ have been estimated by maximum, or restricted maximum, likelihood. Then the parametric residual bootstrap proceeds as follows (I have only outlined the first step as that is all I need for the question)

(1) Simulate $e^*_{ij} \sim N(0, \hat{\sigma}^2_e)$ $(i = 1,2, \dots , I_j; j = 1, \dots, J)$. Further, simulate the $1 \times (K+1)$ row vector $u^*_j = (u^*_{j0}, u^*_{j1}, \dots, u^*_{jK})$ from the $(K+1)$ - dimensional normal distribution $N(0, \hat{\Sigma})$ for $j = 1, \dots, J$.

...

For the nonparametric bootstrap, where we do not assume that the random class effects follow a $(K+1)$- dimensional normal distribution, nor do we assume that the $e_{ij}$ are normally distributed, we have the following procedure. Once again the parameters $(\beta, \Sigma, \sigma^2_e)$ have been estimated by maximum, or restricted maximum, likelihood

(1) Calculate the residuals at level 1, $\{\hat{e}_{ij}\}_{(i = 1,2, \dots , I_j; j = 1, \dots, J)}$, and level 2, $\{\hat{u}_j\}_{j = 1, \dots, J}$. Noting that the $\hat{u}_j$ are $1 \times (K+1)$ row vectors.

...

But how can this be done? We have

\begin{equation}
\hat{e}_{ij} = y_{ij} - \sum_{k=0}^K\hat{\beta}_kx_{ijk} - \sum_{k=0}^K\hat{u}_{jk}z_{ijk}, 
\end{equation}

but we do not know what the $\hat{u}_{jk}$ are. Similarly, one cannot obtain the $\hat{u}_{jk}$ without knowing the $\hat{e}_{ij}$.

Can anyone explain how the first step of the non-parametric procedure is done?

Comment: Since the parameters $(\beta, \Sigma, \sigma^2_e)$ have been estimated before step one of the nonparametric approach (and before the parametric approach), perhaps these values are used in some nonparametric way to estimate $\{\hat{e}_{ij}\}_{(i = 1, \dots, I_j; j = 1, \dots, J)}$, and the $\{\hat{u}_j\}_{j=1,\dots, J}$?

I am unfamiliar to the methods used in nonparametric statistics so perhaps I am missing something.